# Key usage not applied using Microsoft CA

Tags: certificate-authority, microsoft, key-usage

I'm a bit of a newbie to Certificate signing, so please forgive any stupid questions I might have.

I have a CSR, when I decode the CSR it cleary request the following key usages:

```
Requested Extensions:
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
```

I have an enterprise Root CA (which is offline) and a subordinate CA. 
On my subordinate CA, I have a template with the appropriate Public Key Usage 
[image: Public Key Usage List]

Yet, when I sign my CSR using the appropriate template, the Key Usage is not added.

[image: Certificate]

Any toughts on How I can resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the Key Usage is added, but it doesn't match what your template says.  Is that your actual concern?  Or is it that Extended Key Usage isn't added?